# Google App Engine Content Management

Tags: google-app-engine, flask

I have a web application written in Flask and hosted on Google App Engine. I like to add content management functionality to it.

Specifically I want to add the ability to generate content(HTML) dynamically using forms.

Whats the best approach to take. Does App Engine have features that can make this easy for me ?

Comment: http://magic.gae-init.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a framework optimized for Datastore to build such applications.

I've never use this, but this framework seems to have functions for generating CRUD from models.
http://ferris-framework.appspot.com/docs/index.html

This framework, I built some apps with this, also has same functions.
http://kay-docs.shehas.net/index.html